# Exporting a function from Vue's "<script setup>" like from a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I would like to export a function from a component from within the "" section and use it in another component.

I tried it like this:

```
<!-- TestHeading.vue -->
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const title = ref('title');

export function set_title(new_title) {
  title.value = new_title;
}
</script>

<!-- TestDocument.vue -->
<template>
  <TestHeading />
  <p>Main text</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { TestHeading, set_title } from '../components/TestHeading.vue';
set_title('new title');
</script>
```

This just gives me the error: `<script setup> cannot contain ES module exports. If you are using a previous version of <script setup>, please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227.`

Omitting the "export" I just get:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: set_title` in TestDocument.vue.

Is there a way to do it?
The component (TestHeading) will only appear once in the whole document, so I should be able to set the title using a global function like this.

***Update:*** Found my workaround, instead of exporting the function, I just set `window.set_title = (new_title) => { ... }`. Does not seem so clean, but I am probably going to use this unless I find a better way.

Comment: Do not export from `<script setup>`. You place it in a separate file and export it. Then you import it into every `<script setup>` which might need it. `<script setup>` is at the receiving end of the `import/export` equation. `<script setup>` already has an export. If you want to modify it, you might want to use normal `<script>` for this component.

Comment: But, again, exporting anything else than the actual component from a `.vue` file is an anti-pattern. Do not use it. Anything you want to re-use should be placed in `.js|ts` files and imported in the `.vue` components needing them.

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the function using [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) macro, then use a template ref on the child component :

```html
<!-- TestHeading.vue -->
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const title = ref('title');

 function set_title(new_title) {
  title.value = new_title;
}

defineExpose({
  set_title
})
</script>
```

```html
<!-- TestDocument.vue -->
<template>
  <TestHeading ref="heading" />
  <p>Main text</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { TestHeading } from '../components/TestHeading.vue';

const heading = ref()

heading.value.set_title('new title');
</script>
```

But it's recommended to use a prop or slot :

```html
<!-- TestHeading.vue -->
<template>
  <h1>
    <slot/>
  </h1>
</template>

<script setup>

</script>
```

```html
<!-- TestDocument.vue -->
<template>
  <TestHeading >
     {{title}}
  </TestHeading> 
 <p>Main text</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { TestHeading} from '../components/TestHeading.vue';

const title = ref('title');

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However both of your versions give me the same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: set_title in TestDocument.vue

Comment: @betterworld `set_title` should be removed